# I am having issues with jwcrypto and crypotgraphy installation. I have tried to install it multiple times but same issue occurs all the time

Tags: python, openssl

I am having issues with jwcrypto and crypotgraphy installation. I have tried to install it multiple times but same issue occurs all the time:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.295]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\KIIT>pip install python_jwt
Collecting python_jwt
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/30/35/df19a7eba32898dc89a99d597c9595f2e78c896c6a5c32decf786b751af5/python_jwt-3.2.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jwcrypto>=0.6.0 (from python_jwt)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f0/0d/00173a6aee1025e529b21c365182c8d06e78b1beb98d5633f841da6f122e/jwcrypto-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cryptography>=1.5 (from jwcrypto>=0.6.0->python_jwt)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/95/f43d02315f4ec074219c6e3124a87eba1d2d12196c2767fadfdc07a83884/cryptography-2.7.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\kiit\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' 'c:\users\kiit\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\KIIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-79umwzhl\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.6.0' wheel 'cffi>=1.8,!=1.11.3; python_implementation != '"'"'PyPy'"'"''
       cwd: None
  Complete output (42 lines):
  Collecting setuptools>=40.6.0
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b2/86/095d2f7829badc207c893dd4ac767e871f6cd547145df797ea26baea4e2e/setuptools-41.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/83/b4a77d044e78ad1a45610eb88f745be2fd2c6d658f9798a15e384b7d57c9/wheel-0.33.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/1a/ab8c62b5838722f29f3daffcc8d4bd61844aa9b5f437341cc890ceee483b/cffi-1.12.3.tar.gz
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\kiit\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\KIIT\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-2fjh5djg\\cffi\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\KIIT\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-2fjh5djg\\cffi\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
           cwd: C:\Users\KIIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2fjh5djg\cffi\
      Complete output (30 lines):
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\users\kiit\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 489, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
          return self.find_available_vc_vers()[-1]
      IndexError: list index out of range

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\KIIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2fjh5djg\cffi\setup.py", line 127, in <module>
          if sys.platform == 'win32' and uses_msvc():
        File "C:\Users\KIIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2fjh5djg\cffi\setup.py", line 105, in uses_msvc
          return config.try_compile('#ifndef _MSC_VER\n#error "not MSVC"\n#endif')
        File "c:\users\kiit\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 225, in try_compile
          self._compile(body, headers, include_dirs, lang)
        File "c:\users\kiit\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\command\config.py", line 132, in _compile
          self.compiler.compile([src], include_dirs=include_dirs)
        File "c:\users\kiit\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 346, in compile
          self.initialize()
        File "c:\users\kiit\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 239, in initialize
          vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
        File "c:\users\kiit\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 185, in msvc14_get_vc_env
          return EnvironmentInfo(plat_spec, vc_min_ver=14.0).return_env()
        File "c:\users\kiit\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 843, in __init__
          self.si = SystemInfo(self.ri, vc_ver)
        File "c:\users\kiit\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 485, in __init__
          self.vc_ver = vc_ver or self._find_latest_available_vc_ver()
        File "c:\users\kiit\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 492, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
          raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(err)
      distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
      ----------------------------------------

  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\kiit\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' 'c:\users\kiit\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\KIIT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-79umwzhl\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=40.6.0' wheel 'cffi>=1.8,!=1.11.3; python_implementation != '"'"'PyPy'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Error occurs while installing cryptography. I am using python 3.8.0.

Comment: I have also tried to install cryptography module using pip install cryptography